# Javascript: Bullet animation follow direct path

Tags: javascript, animation, geometry, game-physics

I'm working on a JS game. At some point a character's bullet needs to travel and hit a target from any angle. Ive tried something like this in the game loop:

```
if (bx < targetX-speed) bx += speed;
if (bx > targetX+speed) bx -= speed;
if (by < targetY-speed) by += speed;
if (by > targetY+speed) by -= speed;
```

Obviously it can only travel at 0 and 45 degree angles and that just looks horrible.

I thought of bringing geometry into play by calculating the angle before the bullet fires as such:

```
angle = Math.atan((by-targetY)/(bx-targetX));
```

Knowing the angle I can probably calculate either bx or by increasing one parameter i.e.:

```
by += speed;
bx = by*Math.tan(angle);
```

The only problem is that I cant do both at once. And I wouldn't be able to use the same for all angles.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Thanks in advance <3
Walt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the solution (though personally I'd use sin instead of tan because tan is discontinuous). The only thing is you're confusing the coordinate system.

The solution is:

```
angle = Math.atan((shooterY-targetY)/(shooterX-targetX));
```

Calculate that only once when the bullet is fired then store that angle in a variable. Then you can do:

```
by += speed;
bx = by*Math.tan(angle);
```

---

#### Additional answer

My personally preferred solution is:

```
var dy = shooterY-targetY;
var dx = shooterX-targetX;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dy*dy+dx*dx);
var angle = Math.asin(dy/distance);
```

Then calculate dy and dx for the bullet:

```
var speed = SOME_SPEED;
var b_dy = Math.sin(angle) * speed;
var b_dx = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
```

Then move the bulled each frame:

```
by += b_dy;
bx += b_dx;
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Your solution works perfectly :)

Comment: A quicker way to compute the angle of a vector `var v = {x : ?, y : ?}` is `var ang = Math.atan2(v.y, v.x)' It returns the angle from `-Math.PI to Math.PI`